# Retrieve an user list sorted by the number of object created containing a given parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Im developing an API in Javascript and using MongoDB as my DB (mongoose v5.9.26).

Im facing this really tough mongoose query creation, and I would love some help to figure out the proper way to build it using Mongoose.

Given the Object schema provided below, I would like to retrieve a user list ([createdBy]), sorted by the number of Object creation made by an user in a category received in parameter.
I would receive in a Get query a body containing the Category.

```
export const ObjectSchema = new Schema({
    createdBy:          { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    title:              { type: String, required: true },
    category:           { type: CategorySchema, required: false },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

I would like to avoid querying all the Objects containing the category received in parameter and do all the sort logic in javascript.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For those happening to face the situation that's how i have been able to build my query, integrating pagination.

```
     const group = await this.timenoteModel.aggregate([
        { $match: { 'category.category': { $regex: category.category, $options: 'i'}, 'category.subcategory': {$regex: category.subcategory, $options: 'i'} } },
        { $group: {
                _id: '$createdBy',
                count: { $sum: 1 },
            }},
        { $sort: { count: -1 } },
        { $skip: offset * USER_PAGINATE_LIMIT },
        { $limit: USER_PAGINATE_LIMIT }
    ]);

    const users = await this.userModel.populate(group, {path: '_id'});
```